# how to fix textviews on image on different resolutions on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 3 textviews 100, 300 and 500, I want to fix them on image like below.

[image]

my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:layoutDirection="ltr"
    tools:context="com.kortexta.pandaz.MainActivity"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<ImageView
    android:src="@drawable/bg"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/kk"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="202dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView3" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="19dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView4" />

<TextView
    android:text="TextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView4"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:id="@+id/textView5" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

but when I run my app on different devices with different resolutions, I get results like below:

[image]

and

[image]

how can fix textviews on different resolutions?
please help me.

Comment: Are you placing the Text views and the background dynamically or is this a layout? do the text views need to change?

Comment: No, it's layout and textviews values are changed dynamically.

Comment: can you provide the layout then? its hard to tell you whats going wrong when you cant look at the layout :)

Comment: I think it is better if you make the content as an image and android studio helps generate drawable for each screen resolution.

Comment: @BAAAZINGA I added my layout.

Answer (score 0):

is the TextViewhaving some kind of pentagon background?
If yes then keep your images for each resolution in mipmap.